# Write a property from a jar

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello I wrote a game in Java using Eclipse and I manage preferences through a  class that reads / writes a configuration txt file.
When I run it from eclipse everything works fine but when I run it from the jar I created both reading and writing do not work.
I managed to fix the reading problem using getResourceAsStream but I do not know how to solve the writing problem.
This is the code I use to read the file:

```
try {
     InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/configuration.txt");
     Properties properties = new Properties();
     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
     properties.load(br);
     br.close(); 
}
```

and properties.getProperty to get values. 
Works both from Eclipse and jar.

This is the code I tried to write the file:

```
try {
     properties.setProperty("playerColor", value);
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/res/configuration.txt");
     OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
     properties.store(osw, null);
     osw.close();
}
```

Does not work in any case, it says it can not find the file.

How can I fix that? Also, I have to use the class Properties in the code.

Thanks

**MORE INFO**

I use two csv file to save records and games and a txt file for configuration, that are located in the package "res" this way:

```
Project Folder
    --- classpath
    --- bin
    --- src
        --- project
        --- res
            --- records.csv
            --- save.csv
            --- configuration.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all a jar is an archive, which isn't meant to be changed.
So the right solution would be to write to an external source.
You could create a folder and put all data from your game inside that folder (statistics, save files, etc)

Comment: Thank you. So when I run the jar I must not use the files in my "res" package but I should create copies of them in a folder of the pc and read / write these?

Comment: Reorganized the jar, now all works fine. Thanks again.